# Ajax - Pass variable out of loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, youtube-javascript-api

I'm having a weird problem with Ajax, I have to pass a variable "list_videoid" out of a loop. This variable collects the list of videos id and the idea is to print them in this way:

```
'asf2324xfes', '3r32r32fdsfas', '23fsafasfs',
```

This value must go inside "playlist = [list_videoid]".

When I directly paste the code of the videos within the playlist:

```
playlist = ['asf2324xfes', '3r32r32fdsfas', '23fsafasfs',]
```

The music does start playing, but if I use the variable:

```
playlist = [list_videoid]
```

...the music does not play.

I already did the test with "console.log (list_videoid)" and it does print the list of ids correctly. I do not know if I'm failing something.

```
jQuery(function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'http://test/api.php',
            data : $("#buscar_cancion").serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
                var list_videoid= '';
                for ( var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                    list_videoid += "'"+data[i].idvideo+"',";
                }

            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            playlist = [list_videoid];      
            playlistTit = [];

            console.log(list_videoid); //'t_shSXXV91w','2dsf234f',

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one above query answer

1.You could also define a more local variable using **let** (because var inside the for loop will always erase the same variable whereas **let** will be a new variable each time, only accessible for a for iteration)

2.You can achieve using forEach function instead of the for loop.

for example:

```
channels.forEach(function(aChannel){
    //insert here your ajax call using aChannel instead of channels[i]
});
for(var i = 0:i<channels.length;i++){
    let myChannel = channels[i];
    // the reset of your code
}
```